# Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.

The drush command 'en admin_toolbar' could not be executed.

Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

above issue facing while running the command in Drupal 8 project

Comment: What OS? What version of Drupal exactly? What version of `drush --version` exactly? From what directory exactly are you executing the command? Your Drupal project is living in what directory exactly? Did you build your Drupal project with a Composer template?

Comment: macOS Catalina. latest  drush  version 10.